# Where can I find example of Lagrange multipliers and constrained optimization?

Tags: homework, optimization, constrained-optimization

I want give some extra homework about Lagrange multipliers and constrained optimization.  I am interested in examples that are complex (for example, those having more than two variables and more than one restriction).  Where I can find sufficient examples for students' practice?

Comment: I need any webpage address that contains these examples.

Comment: Just curious, is this for a calculus class? I'm tutoring multivariable calculus and this could be of help.

Comment: Yes @Fantini . I need more examples for Economics students in Calculus class (Math II).

Comment: Ask the Economics faculty for relevant, simple to explain, examples? You might substitute "realistic" functions by simpler ones with roughly the right behaviour.

Comment: @vonbrand I need exapmles.

Comment: By quick google search I have found these: http://math.berkeley.edu/~scanlon/m16bs04/ln/16b2lec3.pdf or http://banach.millersville.edu/~BobBuchanan/math311/Lagrange/main.pdf --- It is in the spirit of your question or do you need more sophisticated examples? (You can also try to get some applied examples from physics in book about analytical mechanic)

Comment: @MarkusKlein I need more examples as like as http://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=%28log%282x%2C3%29%2B2x%5E2%29%2F%283x%5E2-sin%283x%2B1%29%5E2%29

Comment: @Huseyin Sorry, but I don't understand the kind of example you want to have. On the given link there is only a function to be minimized without contraints. Can you maybe specify your question with an example related to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple examples you can try:

1) Maximize the product of $n$ positive numbers, given their sum is one.

2)Maximize entropy of $p_1,\dots, p_n$ (all $p_i>0$, summing to one) that is maximizing  $-\sum p_i \log p_i$.

3)  More conditions: Maximizing entropy, but with the extra condition that 
    $ \sum a_i p_i = \mu$.  You can also try introducing more conditions (variance?). The $a_i$s are known constants.

4) You can find a few more good problems here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~thomases/W11_16C1_lec_2_4_11.pdf

5)  A few more good problems here:  http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~dcabrera/practice_exams/topics/lagrangemultipliers.html

Comment: Second link was exactly which I had needed.